# Handling ANSI codes in JTextArea

Tags: java, jtextarea, rxtx

I am implementing new tool which supports serial communication using RxTx library.
My environment here is:
Provided user interface to execute commands and display input from serail connection.
My Problem here is:
when i am reading data from serial port it was printing some specail characters like:

0[m, <-m... which i dont want to print in terminal.

so how to restrict those values from my serial reader.

this is my code to read data from inputstream which is there in serialEvent(SerialPortEvent evt) function.

```
int length = input.available();
byte[] array = new byte[length];
int numBytes = input.read(array);
  for (int i = 0; i < numBytes; i++) {
    if (array[i] != Constants.NEW_LINE_ASCII) {
    logText = new String(new byte[] {array[i]});
    textArea.append(logText);
  } else {
    textArea.append("\n");
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tell the device not to send them.

Comment: how to tell, can you please provide indetail.

Comment: How to tell what? You haven't told us what the device is. How could anyone know how to tell it anything?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the environment variable `TERM` to `dumb` to let your system know that your terminal is a very basic one